# How to solve conflicts in order to create a pull request to the main repository from my forked repository?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repository from github. Now, I have made some changes in the file which I have forked. Now I want to merge my changes to the main repository. When I try to merge the file directly it shows me that there are conflicts in the code. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As it asks you to do - You'll have to resolve the conflicts first.

Comment: the body of your question is really different than your title...

Comment: `man git-rebase`, and rebase your branch. Do not attempt to merge as others are advising you, and manually resolve the conflict. Most repo owners will reject merge requests that had a conflict. This is fine for your own internal repos, but pull requests with conflicts are almost certain to be rejected. I know I would reject such a pull request. Resolve the conflict by rebasing your branch.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you are looking for is to resolve merge conflicts you can use something called `git mergetool` [here](https://gist.github.com/karenyyng/f19ff75c60f18b4b8149).

You can get more info about `mergetool` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163659/4014678).

You can find out about resolving `merge` conflicts [here](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/).

Hope this helps.